# javascript function arguments

Tags: javascript

i want to pass an array to a function and work on it,but i am afraid ,error occurs saying board_pt is undefined. What is the problem? This is the code :

```
function set_boardPoint( board_pt,turn)
{   
    var no = board_pt.number-1;
    board[no].row = board_pt.row;
    board[no].col = board_pt.col;
    board[no].x = board_pt.x;
    board[no].y = board_pt.y;
    board[no].value = turn;
    board[no].number = board_pt.number;
}
```

board is a global array already defined

Comment: can you show how you're calling set_boardPoint?

Comment: I would suggest you to concentrate on the error message. If board_pt is `undefined` then it probably means what it says.

Comment: var previous_boardPoint=board[i];

Comment: set_boardPoint(previous_boardPoint,0);This is the way i am calling it

Comment: And how is `previous_boardPoint` defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that  board_pt have only 1 item, and js in these case know  board_pt as object:

```
function set_boardPoint( board_pt,turn)
{   
    var no = board_pt.number-1;
  if( board[no] != undefined ) 
  {
    board[no].row = board_pt.row;
    board[no].col = board_pt.col;
    board[no].x = board_pt.x;
    board[no].y = board_pt.y;
    board[no].value = turn;
    board[no].number = board_pt.number;
}else
{
 board.row = board_pt.row;
    board.col = board_pt.col;
    board.x = board_pt.x;
    board.y = board_pt.y;
    board.value = turn;
    board.number = board_pt.number;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `board_pt` is a real array, then it's unlikely that it has a property named `number`. Do you mean `length`?

Comment: the array board[i] has board[i].row,...board[i].number and i passed it like this :  previous_boardPoint=board[i]; where var previous_boardPoint=new Array();

Comment: ok i got that as u told ,i am passing object to the function but it still says board_pt is undefined.actually board[] is an array of objects.

Answer (score 0):

From your comments, you have to define the **previous_boardPoint** as an array. To declare a array in javascript, you need to have - `var previous_boardPoint = [];` in your code. Also have each elements defined (if you have any) like `previous_boardPoint[0] = val1; previous_boarPoint[1] = val2;` etc.

If these things are not in your code, then in all likely possibilities, you will get **board_pt** as undefined in your function **set_boardPoint**.